# The four runner problem/conjecture

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, conjectures, open-problem

I've recently read [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheFourRunnerProblem/) the following problem, called « four-runner problem » :

> Suppose four runners (represented by labeled spheres) run around a circular track. Their speeds are constant positive rationals $v_1<v_2<v_3<v_4$.
>
> At time $0$, all the runners are together at the starting gate; shortly after, they are arranged in the order $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, counting from the starting gate. The order changes to $\{4, 1, 2, 3\}$ when runner 4 passes the starting gate. Then either runner 3 passes the starting gate, runner 4 laps runner 1, or the two events happen at the same time, giving possible orders $\{3, 4, 1, 2\}$, $\{1, 4, 2, 3\}$, or $\{3, 1, 2, 4\}$.
>   […]
>
> The answer to this question is unknown: **which rates generate all 24 possible orders?**
>
> For three runners, all six orders are achieved if and only if the two slower rates do not add up to the fast rate.

For instance, I found that the rates $0.1 < 0.2 < 0.61 < 0.9$ generate the 24 possible combinations.

I would like to know where to find more information on that problem. Are there some research articles about it? I didn't find anything, even for the case with 3 runners (which does not seem obvious to me).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the length of the track?

Comment: I think this is 1. In some sense, we are considering the maps $t \mapsto t \cdot v_j \pmod 1$ for $1 \leq j \leq 4$.

Comment: Presumably, then, the speeds are not integers but positive rationals? Or reals?

Comment: @Justpassingby : I noticed that. The speeds are positive rationals, say.

Comment: The speeds in the original link are constant integers.

Comment: [The lonely runner conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_runner_conjecture) is similar - it says that each runner in such a scenario will be a "far" from the others at some time. It is unproven for $8$ or more runners.

Comment: @Downvoter : may I ask about this downvote?

Comment: In February 2016, G. Beck wrote me this : « [This problem] was my master's problem assigned to me in 1970 or so by George White
(since deceased) at the University of British Columbia. I failed to
solve it.
…

Comment: … 
However, I found a symmetry: the number of permutations achieved for
rates r1, r2, r3, r4 is the same as that for r4, r4-r1, r4-r2, r4-r3.
Here is why. Think of the starting point as runner 0 with rate 0.
(Runner 0 breaks the cycle, giving the starting point.) Rotate the plane
by -r4 so that the rates for the five runners are are now -r4, r1-r4,
r2-r4, r3-r4, 0. (Runner 4 now becomes stationary.) Look at the plane
from the other side: the rates are 0, r4-r3, r4-r2, r4-r1, r4. »

Answer (score 10):

*(This is really a long comment, not an answer intended to attract up- or downvotes, acceptance or bonus - it's just not comfortable typing it in the SE comments format)*

The problem becomes more symmetric if we award the starting point a velocity $v_0.$ The order of the runners changes whenever the time $t$ is an integer multiple of the reciprocal of $v_i-v_j$ for some $i>j\geq0.$ In fact we could even eliminate the condition $v_0<v_1<\cdots<v_n$ and and ask under which conditions on the $v_k$ the runners are guaranteed to reach at least once the order defined by the numbers on their back; the condition $v_i\neq v_j$ for $i\neq j$ then becomes part of the answer rather than part of the problem statement, and we could rephrase:

*Which half-lines starting from the origin in $\mathbb R^n$ intersect the $n$-fold periodic set defined by translating the interior of the unit simplex $0<x_1<\ldots<x_n<1$ along the unit cubic $n$-dimensional lattice?*

There are $C^n_2$ interesting quantities to compare:

$$\begin{matrix}
v_1(-v_0)&v_2(-v_0)&\cdots&v_{n-1}(-v_0)&v_n(-v_0)\\
&v_2-v_1&\cdots&v_{n-1}-v_1&v_n-v_1\\
&&\ddots&&\vdots\\
&&&v_{n-1}-v_{n-2}&v_{n}-v_{n-2}\\
&&&&v_{n}-v_{n-1}\\
\end{matrix}$$

Any equality between two of these quantities - in fact, any equality between integer multiples of the reciprocals of two of these quantities - could theoretically cause the runners to complete a full race without ever reaching a particular given order, although many of these equalities are excluded if we assume $v_0<v_1<v_2<\cdots<v_n.$ It is therefore curious that for $n=3$ only one equality, namely, $v_3-v_2=v_1-v_0$ (or, equivalently, $v_3-v_1=v_2-v_0$) effectively prevents some permutations to be reached - it is no problem if, say, $v_2-v_1=v_3-v_2$ which means that the three runners overtake each other always at exactly the same moment.

In 4 dimensions we have, as a necessary condition, that every subset consisting of 3 runners (or 4, counting the starting point as a runner) has to satisfy the 3-dimensional condition, so we know that

$$\eqalign{
v_1+v_2&\neq v_3(+v_0)\\
v_1+v_2&\neq v_4(+v_0)\\
v_1+v_3&\neq v_4(+v_0)\\
v_2+v_3&\neq v_4(+v_0)\\
v_1+v_4&\neq v_2+v_3\\
}$$

One attempt to answer the question could be to try and prove that these five conditions together are also sufficient.

Putting $v_0=0$ again and $v_4=1$ (because the problem is homogeneous in the $v_i$) these five conditions divide the 3-dimensional unit simplex $0\leq v_1\leq v_2\leq v_3\leq 1$ into an number of sub-simplices (at most 32, I haven't figured out the exact number) along the following boundaries:

$$\eqalign{
v_1+v_2&= v_3\\
v_1+v_2&= 1\\
v_1+v_3&= 1\\
v_2+v_3&= 1\\
v_1+1&= v_2+v_3\\
}$$

Suggestion: identify these sub-simplices and prove for every sub-simplex separately that all 24 permutations are reached when $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is in the interior of the sub-simplex.

Comment: I have received 6 upvotes despite my request to the contrary - thank you for the recognition but if this results in an automatic bounty award then I will use the bounty to further promote this interesting (and unresolved) question.

Comment: As announced, my intent was to draw attention; I was not really hoping to get a complete answer (though this would be welcome, of course). And your input is very valuable, so I award the bounty without hesitation.